# SQL Least Earning Location Count

Tags: sql

I am using an online editor to solve query

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/

have the following SQL Table

```
create table CITIES(id int, name String);
create table USERS(id int, city_id String, name String, email);
create table RIDES(id int, user_id int, distance int, fare int);

INSERT INTO CITIES (id, name) VALUES
(1,"Cooktown"),
(2,"South Suzanne");

INSERT INTO USERS (id, city_id, name, email) VALUES
(1,2,"a","email"),
(2,2,"b","email"),
(3,1,"c","email"),
(4,1,"d","email"),
(5,1,"e","email"),
(5,1,"f","email");

INSERT INTO RIDES (id, user_id, distance, fare) VALUES
(1,1,21,200),
(2,3,6,55),
(3,2,30,230),
(4,2,16,125),
(5,2,11,110),
(6,6,30,285),
(7,3,18,170),
(8,1,6,50),
(9,2,4,40),
(10,1,10,90),
(11,5,11,95),
(12,5,16,140),
(13,4,24,220),
(14,6,17,160),
(15,2,23,205),
(16,2,11,90),
(17,6,5,50),
(18,3,19,180),
(19,5,22,205),
(20,4,6,60);
```

**Output should be :**

South Suzanne 1050

Cooktown 1710

I tried following SQL Query but don't know how to count

```
select c.name, SUM(r.fare) from CITIES c
  left join USERS u on c.id=u.city_id 
  left join RIDES r on u.id=r.user_id
```

**Getting following output**

Cooktown|2705

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS is this for? You've got 3 different ones mentioned in your tags.

Comment: @user11229655 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your reputation should know how to appropriate tag a database on a question.  Only tag the database you are actually using.

Comment: Unrelated, but: that site seems to teach bad SQL. `"Cooktown"` is an identifier in SQL. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `'Cooktown'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(r.fare) [SumOfFare]
FROM CITIES c
  LEFT JOIN USERS u ON c.id=u.city_id 
  LEFT JOIN RIDES r ON u.id=r.user_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY SUM(r.fare) ASC;
```

Also, you might want to add an ORDER BY clause too, so you can see the least earning location at the top.

Comment: Why not use INNER JOIN between USERS and RIDES table ?

Comment: Because not all records in the CITIES table will have matching records in the USERS or RIDERS tables. So some cities might have a total fare amount of 0, because no one travelled in that city.